# How to detect Collision on specific Object?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Let's suppose we have two cylinders in the scenes with red and blue materials on them. Also, we have two UI images with red and blue background. Now, what should I do to make the red image only draggable onto red cylinder and the blue image only draggable onto blue cylinder.
If I drag the red image onto the blue cylinder, then an error message should appear:
same for dragging blue image on red cylinder or vice versa.

See the picture below

[image: Example]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class wrench : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool Dragging = false;
    public bool collision = false;
    Vector3 position;
    public List<GameObject> UIimages;

    public void BeginDrag() {

        position = gameObject.transform.position;
        Dragging = true;
        foreach (GameObject obj in UIimages) {
            obj.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ().enabled = false;
        }
    }

    public void Drag() {
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    public void Drop() {
        if (!collision) {
            gameObject.transform.position = position;
        }
        Dragging = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use colliders and tags to chek it, you know how they work?

Comment: @Lotan i know but i dont know that how to use them in this case because in future if i have so many objects in my scene i will have to write separate separate script for each of them

Comment: @Lotan dragging is working very fine i just want that red can only be dragable on one red cylinder same for blue

Comment: @Lotan please check my question i have posted the code now in this code i used the list which disables all the colliders on other objects but how to enable it back like if i am done with dragging red image on red cylinder then i want to drag blue image on blue cylinder but it cant detects the collision because its collider is disabled

Comment: Sorry Nouman but I don't get your point, try to explain it different ^^'

Comment: Tag is the best way to go. You don't need to create a different tag for each object in your scene, you just tag them with the same label. In your case you can have a `red` tag and a `blue` tag, compare them... if they are not equal, display the error. If tagging is not something you want, then you need to search for another common attribute, or create prefabs and check the types,

Comment: Is the collision itself working already? E.g. using OnTriggerEnter etc?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dropps are already detected as you say and the question is more about how to differ between the objects I would use a simple `enum` e.g.

```
public enum WhichObject
{
    red,
    blue
}
```

the advantage is that later you can very easily add more options without having to deal with layers, tags etc.

On the GameObject you drag around add a component e.g.

```
public class ObjectInformation
{
    public WhichObject IsObject;
}
```

and simply select in the Inspector (or if you spawn them via script) for each of your dragged objects which value the `WhichObject` variable shall have.

Than on your target objects where you detect the collision also add a `WhichObject` variable but this time configure the value you expect to be dropped here

```
public WhichObject ExpectedObject;
```

again set it via the inspector or script.

Than simply add a check

```
var info = droppedObject.GetComponent<ObjectInformation>();

// Something else dropped?
if(!info) return;

// Now check if the value matches
// the one this object expects
if(info.IsObject == ExpectedObject)
{
    // Correct object
    Debug.Log("Yeah!");
} 
else 
{
    // Wrong object
    Debug.LogFormat("Dropped object {0} does not match the expected object {1}!", info.IsObject, ExpectedObject);
}
```

---

Later you can also simply extend it using multiple enums like e.g. colors, forms etc.

And maybe you could as well make the check the other way round and check on the dragged object, if the values match and if the don't match not even allow to be dropped on that target object (this depends of course on your implementation).